# R freezes when I call a C code

Tags: c, r

I wrote a small C code to do random walk metropolis, which I call in R. When I run it, R freezes. I am not sure which part of the code is incorrect. I following this [Peng and Leeuw tutorial](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/interface.pdf) (on Page 6). As a disclaimer: I don't have much experience with C, and have only some basic knowledge of C++

```
#----C code --------
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

void mcmc(int *niter, double *mean, double *sd, double *lo_bound, 
          double *hi_bound, double *normal)
{
    int i, j;
    double x, x1, h, p;
    x = runif(-5, 5);
    for(i=0; i < *niter; i++) {
        x1 = runif(*lo_bound, *hi_bound);
        while((x1 + x) > 5 || (x1 + x) < -5)
            x1 = runif(*lo_bound, *hi_bound);
        h = dnorm(x+x1, *mean, *sd, 0)/dnorm(x, *mean, *sd, 0);
        if(h >= 1)
            h = 1;
        p = runif(0, 1);
        if(p < h)
            x += x1;
        normal[i] = x;
    }
}


#-----R code ---------
foo_C<-function(mean, sd, lo_bound, hi_bound, niter)
{
    result <- .C("mcmc",  as.integer(niter), as.double(mean), as.double(sd), 
                 as.double(lo_bound), as.double(hi_bound), normal=double(niter))
    result[["normal"]]
}
```

After compiling it:

```
dyn.load("foo_C.so")
foo_C(0, 1, -0.5, 0.5, 100)
```

**FOLLOW UP:**
The `while` loop is where the problem lies. But the root of the problem seems to have to do with the function `runif`, which is supposed to generate a random variable between a lower bound and an upper bound. But it seems that what the function actually does is to randomly pick either the upper bound value (5) or the lower bound value (-5).

Comment: @Alex, I would defintely recommend using `Rcpp` to do this kind of thing. It is supposed to be much less of a headache to integrate `R` and `C\C++` using that package.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks for the suggestion! I've been going through a PowerPoint tutorial by Dirk Eddelbuettel. But since I already wrote a code that unfortunately doesn't work, so I thought I should at least figure out what the problem is :).

Comment: Have you tried to simplify your C code in order to find the line that causes the problem? Maybe you could comment-out everything and add it then line by line back. Maybe you could narrow in that way the problem?!

Comment: Good idea @DanielFischer, maybe first start with printing `Hello World!` from C. That way you can see if the link works at all.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I just did. It seems to have to do with the `while` loop because if I comment out the loop, the function runs with no problem. It seems that the values I try to generate are all smaller than -5...so the while loop gets stuck.

Comment: @Alex what does the runif source code say? Maybe you can hunt it down and past it above?

Comment: You might try putting `setTimeLimit` inside your R code so that, if there's an infinite loop inside the c-call, with any luck you'll at least get control back to the R-console.

Comment: I am actually not sure what is going on here. After R crashed for the 4th time, the same exact C code (I swear!) is working now. So it is no longer stuck in the while-loop, and runif() is behaving the way it should, namely picking a random variable that is between -5 and 5. Is it possible to close this post? - Since I don't really know what the problem is, and there isn't a real solution then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html), section [6.3 Random number generation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Random-numbers) and call `GetRNGstate();` before you call R's random number generation routines.  You also need to call `PutRNGstate();` when you're finished.

The reason your code started working is likely because you called `set.seed` in the R session before you called your `mcmc` C function.

So your C code should look like this:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

void mcmc(int *niter, double *mean, double *sd, double *lo_bound, 
          double *hi_bound, double *normal)
{
    int i;
    double x, x1, h, p;
    GetRNGstate();
    x = runif(-5.0, 5.0);
    for(i=0; i < *niter; i++) {
        x1 = runif(*lo_bound, *hi_bound);
        while((x1 + x) > 5.0 || (x1 + x) < -5.0) {
            x1 = runif(*lo_bound, *hi_bound);
            //R_CheckUserInterrupt();
        }
        h = dnorm(x+x1, *mean, *sd, 0)/dnorm(x, *mean, *sd, 0);
        if(h >= 1)
            h = 1;
        p = runif(0, 1);
        if(p < h)
            x += x1;
        normal[i] = x;
    }
    PutRNGstate();
}
```

Comment: ... which, when you Rcpp, is much easier via the `RNGScope` class which tools like `sourceCpp()` even add automagically for you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Rccp is the next thing on my "to learn" list :D. And Joshua: Thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated.